# Получить итоговую сумму из нескольких массивов

Tags: php, массивы

В базе данных есть ячейки такого типа:

```
--price:
1000;500;450;
--qty
1;3;5
```

В одной ячейке хранится информация о нескольких товарах, вытаскиваю данные с помощью explode().

Данные выводятся в соответствующем порядке:

```
price   qty
1000     1
500      3
450      5
```

Вопрос - как посчитать в таком случае итоговую сумму? исходя из указанного количества в другой ячейке (qty).

Comment: В каком точно формате приходят данные? Как в примере - в одной строке? Или разными? Или просто `1000;500;450;` и `1;3;5`?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, первоначально из бд я получаю одной строкой, потом разделяю их в explode()

Comment: Одной строкой - один в один как в примере?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, да

Comment: @Denis640Kb решил вопрос, сам немного тупнул